# Regal force and cyclonic rift

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I have 2 green creatures out and I cast [Regal Force](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Regal%20Force). My opponent responds by overloading [Cyclonic Rift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cyclonic%20Rift). Do I draw 3, 1, or 0 cards, and does Regal Force get bounced?

Comment: Respond to what exactly the creature being cast or the triggered ability? The correct answer will be different depending on which one.

Answer (score 12):

It depends on what exactly the opponent is responding to. If they cast Cyclonic Rift in response to Regal Force the spell, then Regal Force ends up on the battlefield and you draw 1 card. However, if they respond to Regal Force's triggered ability, then Regal Force instead ends up in your hand and you draw no cards.

## Responding to the spell

If they respond to the spell, then the sequence of actions plays out like this:

1. You cast Regal Force and pass priority. At this point, Regal Force is on the stack.
2. They cast Cyclonic Rift. At this point, Regal Force is on the stack, and Cyclonic Rift is on top of it.
3. Cyclonic Rift resolves, returning your two creatures on the battlefield to your hand.
4. Regal Force resolves and it enters the battlefield. Its ability triggers.
5. Regal Force's ability resolves, and you draw 1 card for the 1 creature you control.

## Responding to the triggered ability

If they respond to the triggered ability, the sequence of actions instead plays out like this.

1. You cast Regal Force.
2. Your opponent declines to respond, and Regal Force resolves. It enters the battlefield, and its ability triggers. At this point, the triggered ability is on the stack.
3. They cast Cyclonic Rift. At this point, Regal Force's triggered ability is on the stack, and Cyclonic Rift is on top of it.
4. Cyclonic Rift resolves, returning your three creatures on the battlefield to your hand.
5. Regal Force's ability resolves, and you draw no cards because you control no creatures.

Answer (score 2):

If the opponent responds to you casting Regal Force, the following would happen:

- Regal Force is cast and goes on stack
- Cyclonic Rift is cast and goes on stack
- Cyclonic Rift resolves, two green creatures return to your hand
- Regal Force comes into play and triggers
- You draw one card

If the opponent casts Rift after after Regal Force comes into play:

- Regal Force is cast and goes on stack
- Regal Force resolves, comes into play and triggers, trigger goes on stack
- Opponent casts Rift, it goes on stack
- Rift resolves, 2 creatures and Force return to your hand
- Trigger resolves, you control no creatures and draw zero cards.

Answer (score 0):

You're question is a little bit unclear. If he responds to you playing the regal force by bouncing everything then the force will come into play, it's ability will  trigger and seeing as the regal force is a green creature  you will draw one card.

If he on the other hand lets the regal force resolve and respond to the trigger by bouncing all your critters then unless you can flash in a green creature before the ability resolves the ability will see zero green creatures and you will also draw zero cards.

Comment: This answer gives the same information the existing answers, but a day later and with less detail.